# ElasticSearch range query with value greater than 11457987 causes server error

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do a range query with lt or lte set to 11457988 I get this error

I am using ElasticSearch 1.6x

```
{
  "errors": [
    "internal server error"
  ]
}
```

When I do a range query with lt or lte set to 11457987 I get no error and it returns results

```
{
  "took": 243,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6017,
    "max_score": 0.1931922,
    "hits": [
    ...
    ...
```

Here is my query

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "fields":[
                  "SIC*"
               ],
               "query":"13* OR 35*"
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "should":[
                  {
                     "query":{
                        "bool":{
                           "must":[
                              {
                                 "range":{
                                    "ANNUAL_SALES":{
                                       "lte":11457987
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size":10000,
   "from":0
}
```

I also tried setting the number to a string and this allowed me to use a larger number but it also threw a server error at 27000000

Comment: Do see any exception on elasticsearch logs? I am guessing you are hitting some sort of limits on memory.

Comment: What is the mapping of the `ANNUAL_SALES`  field?